# Webforms ReportViewer pagination without showing the toolbar?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I am looking into replacing the ReportViewer toolbar. Just doing discovery right now. I know about the [JavaScript api for the report viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx). This does not include an API for the pagination controls.

I have dug around in the generated HTML and have figured out how to trigger a postback to do the pagination. Calling the following in Javascript works even with the toolbar not being displayed.

`__doPostBack("ReportViewer1$ctl05$ctl00$Next$ctl00")`

I don't know the gotchas of calling a post back like this. As the string being passed into the method is the name of the input button. It seems like the name may be able to change. I also don't know what the $ctl stuff means.

I am aware of how to get reportviewer to not page reports by setting the interactive height to zero. I am just exploring all my options at this time.

Is there an easier way to do pagination without the ReportViewer toolbar being displayed? If not, what are the gotchas of triggering a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to this was to do a postback with customer arguments.

Client Side JS:

```
function loadPage(pageNumber) {
    $('#__EVENTTARGET').val('pagination');
    $('#__EVENTARGUMENT').val(<pageNumberToGoTo>);
    $('#form1').submit();
}
```

The two fields that get populated are what is created by default for ASP.NET postbacks.

Server Side C# in the ASP.NET pages OnLoad event:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "pagination")
{
    int pageNumber = int.Parse(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
    _reportViewer.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
}
```